# How to handle date and time language in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Hello to everyone,

We have developed an auction website and i want to make a change to date and time language,

for example when i post an auction now , into view area we have added date and time to show when the auction was posted,  we have translated our site using __d function and .po files , but we can't translate date and time , so when i make a post the date and time is in English fore example "March 14,2017, 23:00" ,

so how to translate Months ? in this case "March" ?

any suggestion please?

Thanks
Best regards.

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, Our cake version is : 2.0.6

Comment: Reading the documentation helps https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html &&  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Comment: I already have read this , i couldn't using these information any other suggestion or example please?

Comment: Well, what exactly is missing there? What have you not understood? Taken from the linked page: `The i18n functions of CakeTime utility class and helper TimeHelper use these LC_TIME files.` Go there https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper and search for i18nFormat(). Then use that method to get translateable times.